# Finding parametric equations for the tangent line at a point on a curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, parametric

> Find parametric equations for the tangent line at the point $(\cos(-\frac{4 \pi}{6}), \sin(-\frac{4 \pi}{6}), -\frac{4 \pi}{6}))$ on the curve $x = \cos(t), y = \sin(t), z=t$

I understand that in order to find the solution, I need to use partial derivatives. However, the method in my textbook works for simpler problems -- I seem to be making a calculation error when I try to apply the method to this problem.

Can anyone suggest how to approach this problem?

I found a *very* [similar problem and solution here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070403182912AAd4PCr), but the solution by the person who answered is hard for me to follow. Unfortunately, I get stuck at the line where he subtracts $\frac{\pi}{6}$ from $\pi$ within the trigonometric functions.

[Here is the "simple" method that I was originally using.](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32A/chap11/section7/732d45/732_45.html)

Any sincere help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited your title and question. In general try to keep the title short and capture the essence of the problem instead of having the entire problem statement as title.

Answer (score 2):

So $\textbf{r}(t) = \left< \cos t, \sin t, t \right>$. Then $\textbf{r}'(t) = \left<-\sin t, \cos t, 1 \right>$. So $t = -4 \pi/6$. So $\textbf{r'}(-\frac{4 \pi}{6}) = \left<-\sin( -\frac{4 \pi}{6}), \cos \left( -\frac{4 \pi}{6} \right), 1 \right>$. So the equation of the tangent line would be

$$x = \cos(-\frac{4 \pi}{6})+t\left(-\sin\left( -\frac{4 \pi}{6}\right)\right)$$ 
$$y = \sin(-\frac{4 \pi}{6})+t\left(\cos \left(-\frac{4 \pi}{6} \right) \right)$$ 
and $$z = -\frac{4 \pi}{6}+t$$

Comment: Thank you for the great response. Actually, the first two answers (x and y) are what I have been getting--for some reason, they are not considered correct by the program I am using to check the answers, although I am using the same input. Z was considered correct. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your $x$ and $y$ equations are wrong—the given point matches your $z$ equation when $t=0$, but not the $x$ and $y$ equations when $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the answer to which you linked on Yahoo! Answers is just wrong.  The parametric equations $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$, $z=t$ describe a spiral on a cylinder of radius 1 coaxial with the $z$-axis.  Since there is only 1 parameter, these parametric equations cannot describe a 2-dimensional surface.  The method used in your second link seems appropriate—the direction vector of the tangent line at any point on $\langle x(t),y(t),z(t)\rangle=\langle\cos t,\sin t,t\rangle$ is $\langle x'(t),y'(t),z'(t)\rangle=\cdots$ (no partial derivatives needed) and you know a point on the line, so you can write a parametric equation for the tangent line.

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer for $x$ and $y$ are:
$$
\cos(-4\pi/6) + t(-\sin(-4\pi/6))\\
\sin(-4\pi/6) + t(\cos(-4\pi/6))
$$

this is because the point that lies on the parametric lines are defined by inputting the $t$ value into the original parametric equation

Comment: Are you able to show the details, for the benefit of the person who asked the question?

Answer (score 0):

X= cos(-4pi/6) + t(-sin(-4pi/6))
y= sin(-4pi/6) + t(cos(-4pi/6))
z= -4pi/6 + t

x= .9993 + t(0.0365)
y= -0.0365 + t(0.9993)
z= -2.094 + t

All of these values were estimated to 4 digits by plugging in (-4pi/6) into the equations for x,y,z

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format answers using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, when can get exact representations of these equations. Regards